# Mayavi Mlab : Drawing octahedrons

Tags: python, mayavi

I cannot find a way to draw octahedrons. Could someone point me to a class for drawing triangular (transclucent) surfaces at the least?

`tvtk.tools.visual` seems to have only a few basic shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Gallery](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html) has an example of how to use [triangular_mesh](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.triangular_mesh):

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as ML

verts = [(1,-1,0), (1,1,0), (-1,1,0), (-1,-1,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,-1)]
x, y, z = zip(*verts)
# Each triangle is a 3-tuple of indices. The indices are indices of `verts`.
triangles = [(i, (i+1)%4, j) for i in range(4) for j in (4,5)]
colorval = z
ML.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, triangles, scalars=colorval, opacity=0.75)
ML.show()
```

[image]

Comment: could you please take a look at [a followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959421/mayavi-animating-an-octahedron-outline) please?