# Mayavi: animating an octahedron outline without blocking

Tags: python, animation, mayavi

I am trying to animate an octahedron. Here is the code for that. A simpler version of this code would be found [on this different question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952215/mayavi-mlab-drawing-octahedrons). Using the code there and the style of the animate object as used [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html) I tried to make a functional animation. The only problem is- the animation hangs up the plot window!

```py
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as ML
import math
import time

def produce_verts(A,t):
    delta=lambda A,t:A*math.sin(t)
    verts =lambda d: [(1+d,0,0), (0,1+d,0), (-1-d,0,0), (0,-1-d,0), (0,0,1+d), (0,0,-1-d)]
    return zip(*verts(delta(A,t)))

t=0.
dt=0.01
A=0.5
ML.clf()
nverts=6
x, y, z = produce_verts(A,t)
# Each triangle is a 3-tuple of indices. The indices are indices of `verts`.                                                                                                                                        
triangles = [(i, (i+1)%4, j) for i in range(4) for j in (4,5)]
colorval = [x[i]**2+y[i]**2+z[i]**2 for i in range(nverts)]
mesh=ML.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, triangles, scalars=colorval, opacity=1,representation='mesh')
MS=mesh.mlab_source
Bool=True
while Bool:
    t=(t+dt)%(2*math.pi)
    x,y,z=produce_verts(A,t)
    colorval = [x[i]**2+y[i]**2+z[i]**2 for i in range(nverts)]
    MS.reset(x=x,y=y,z=z,scalars=colorval)
    time.sleep(1.)
    print t,dt
    if t>4:
        Bool=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the plot is hanging. It's just that `dt` is so small and the `time.sleep` is so large that it tries your patience. If you set `dt` equal to, say, 0.1, and remove the `time.sleep` call, then the plot becomes more animated.

Also, use `MS.reset` when the *size* of the arrays change. When the size of the arrays stays the same, you'll get better performance using `MS.set`:

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as ML
import math
import time


def produce_verts(A, t):
    def delta(A, t):
        return A * math.sin(t)
    def verts(d):
        return [(1 + d, 0, 0), (0, 1 + d, 0), (-1 - d, 0, 0), (0, -1 - d, 0),
                (0, 0, 1 + d), (0, 0, -1 - d)]
    return zip(*verts(delta(A, t)))

t = 0.
dt = 0.1
A = 0.5
ML.clf()
nverts = 6
x, y, z = produce_verts(A, t)
# Each triangle is a 3-tuple of indices. The indices are indices of `verts`.
triangles = [(i, (i + 1) % 4, j) for i in range(4) for j in (4, 5)]
colorval = [xi ** 2 + yi ** 2 + zi ** 2 for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z)]
mesh = ML.triangular_mesh(
    x, y, z, triangles, scalars=colorval, opacity=1, representation='mesh')
ms = mesh.mlab_source
while True:
    t = (t + dt) % (2 * math.pi)
    x, y, z = produce_verts(A, t)
    colorval = [xi ** 2 + yi ** 2 + zi ** 2 for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z)]
    ms.set(x=x, y=y, z=z, scalars=colorval)
    # time.sleep(0.1)
    print t, dt
    if t > 4:
        break

ML.show()
```